# How do I arrange multiple quotations (each with multiple lines) vertically (with a line through the center) so that they're side-by-side?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, line, quotation

I created the following example in MS Word but I'm unable to recreate it in Overleaf (an online LaTeX editor):
[image: quotations side-by-side]

Below is the code with which I've gotten the closest to creating what I need:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
Text before quotations. \lipsum[3]

\begin{quote}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{lc|c}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{Quotation 1} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{Quotation 2} \\
            \hline
            Multi-line text for column 1 & Multi-line text for column 2 that'd go outside of the page.
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{quote}

Text after quotations. \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

But it's not correct: the columns aren't centered, the line doesn't split the columns at the center, the text isn't divided among both columns, the text isn't placed on a new line when space runs out on the current line, and the text probably won't be justified once it is pasted over multiple lines. See the picture below:

[image: my incorrect formatting]

I'm also unsure whether I'm using the right tools for the job. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Multiline text requires a p{} (tabular), X (tabularx) or possibly a more exotic column type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularray,showframe}
\begin{document}
    Text before quotations.
    
    \begin{quote}
        \begin{center}
        \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[.48\linewidth,l]Q[.48\linewidth,l]},hlines,vlines}
                Quotation 1&Quotation 2 \\
                \hline
                Multi-line text for column 1 & Multi-line text for column 2 that'd go outside of the page.
            \end{tblr}
        \end{center}
    \end{quote}
    Text after quotations.
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: In answr to Yours comments, change the first line of table this way:

```
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[.45\linewidth]|Q[.45\linewidth]},hlines}
```

The output become:

[image]

Change also .45 percentage to adapt to Yours needs.

Comment: You've supplied everything I need to finetune it to my preferences. I settled on .4575 for the percentage and left out`hlines` as well. Much thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution that employs a two-column `tabularx` envrionment, with overall width set to `1\linewidth`, embedded in a `quote` environment. The text within each cell is typeset ragged-right, and the text in the header cells is centered over its respective column and is typeset in italics.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}      % <-- new
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % <-- new

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{quote}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{L|L}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\itshape Quotation 1} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c }{\itshape Quotation 2} \\
\hline
Multi-line text for column 1. Multi-line text for column 1. & 
Multi-line text for column 2 that'd go outside of the page. Multi-line text for column 2 that'd go outside of the page.
\end{tabularx}
\end{quote}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```